# How to properly read all file types with react js and add to IPFS in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4aD4.jpg)

I am trying to read a file (which can be anything like video, image , text ) with react .
I want to add data in the IPFS through Node JS. In normal case(which means when i m only writing in js) I would do it like this :

```
const data = await fs.readFile(file_path)
console.log(data)
const filesAdded = await nodeDialer.add({
    path:file_path,
    content:data,
})
console.log(filesAdded)
```

THe files would be added easily(any type of file).

I tried fs and found out it only works in the node side not on the react side. 
and whereever i looked they were using some readastext functions for .txt file or .csv file.

So a proper solution, I couldn't find.

Comment: Um. Node's [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) and [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) maybe?

Comment: @rayhatfield that, AFAIK, will only run in node environments, i.e. server side. Abhishek, can you update your question with better details? What you've tried so far, where you're stuck or having issues, post your code, what your expected result should be. Try to be a specific as possible.

Comment: @DrewReese He specifically said "in nodejs". If this is in the browser use the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)--assuming the file is going to be chosen by the user in a file input--and then use a browser-compatible [crypto wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-web-crypto). I agree the question needs clarification.

Comment: @rayhatfield Thanks. Just asking for clarification. It's not clear if the OP is trying to run code *in* node, or if they are simply *using* node to run the local development server for react as react is a frontend framework. Maybe they are doing Server Side Rendering (SSR), we don't know.

Comment: now please see the answer @rayhatfield

Comment: @DrewReese see the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with this:

Created a event handler for file upload :

```
  captureFile(event){
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    this.setState({ file_path : file})
    console.log('--------------', this.state.file_path)
    const reader = new window.FileReader()
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      this.setState({ buffer: Buffer(reader.result) })
      console.log('buffer --- ', this.state.buffer)
      console.log('path --- ', this.state.file_path.name)
    }
  }
```

then I add the file in IPFS with :

```
    const filesAdded =  await node.add({
      path: this.state.file_path.name ,
      content:this.state.buffer
    })
```